# Add an extra control to a button in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a code that creates 30 buttons at run time on a form which works excellently

```
For i = 0 To 30
    btn = New Button
    Dim old As Padding = btn.Margin
    Dim old2 As Padding = btn.Padding
    btn.Tag = "X1"
    btn.Name = "Drane"
    btn.Text = "The power of trying"
    btn.Width = 95
    btn.Height = 120
    btn.Margin = New Padding(10, 10, 10, 10)
    btn.Padding = New Padding(0, 4, 0, 2)
    btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter
    btn.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    btn.Font = New Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 11)
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Black
    btn.BackColor = Color.White
Next i
```

Now I'm trying to add an extra control to hold the ids for buttons that I created at run time

```
btn.id = i
```

which would hold the ids of each particular button so I can get the value in other functions in my application. I know I have to add this somehow as a control but I just don't know how.

Please any help will be greatly appreciated in resolving this

Comment: What are you currently using the `Tag` for?

Comment: To hold value unique values for each item

Comment: Ok. I just asked because that is a common place to keep other object information specific to a control. And it looks like you're only ever storing "X1" in your tags at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

This will extend the `Button` class and add an ID property.

```
Public Class ButtonMod
    Inherits Button

    Public Property ID As Integer

End Class
```

Then you just create them in a loop as you were doing already:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 30
    Dim btn As New ButtonMod
    Dim old As Padding = btn.Margin
    Dim old2 As Padding = btn.Padding
    btn.Tag = "X1"
    btn.Name = "Drane"
    btn.Text = "The power of trying"
    btn.Width = 95
    btn.Height = 120
    btn.Margin = New Padding(10, 10, 10, 10)
    btn.Padding = New Padding(0, 4, 0, 2)
    btn.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.BottomCenter
    btn.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopCenter
    btn.Font = New Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", 11)
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Black
    btn.BackColor = Color.White
    btn.ID = i
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, Please where exactly in my code do I place the **Public Class ButtonMod** ? I am getting an error that 'ID is not a member of Button'

Comment: Add it as a new class to your project. Make sure you're creating instances of the new class: Dim btn As New ButtonMod

Comment: You place it outside your main class..i.e `Public Class Form1`

Comment: Thanks, I placed it outside my main class `Public Class Form1` and it still says 'ID is not a member of Button' so I created a new project and tested the code and it works fine. My question is why is it that I can't reference the `btn.ID` in my main project? what could be wrong?

Comment: It is likely because you're creating instances of `Button` and not `ButtonMod`.

Comment: I actually created an instance of ButtonMod `btn = New ButtonMod`

Comment: Do you have Option Explicit On for your form and project?

Comment: No I do not, please Where do I add `Option Explicit` on the form?

Comment: You can just type 'Option Explicit On' at the top of your form. Or even better, right click on your project in Solution Explorer, Properties, Compile Tab and set Option Explicit to On in the Compile Options. This'll help spot if there are any issues with undeclared variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185750/discussion-between-andrew-mortimer-and-smarton).